# How to detect select box height on ios phonegap development?

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova

I want to add an html done button on top of the select box that appear on bottom on ios. I think ill need the select box height in order to do this, any idea how I can get that? If there is another approach to accomplish please let me know.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: done button displays by default. did you use custom plugin for displaying select picker?

Comment: Hi, I changed the photo to better explain the problem. I removed all the plugins and code unrelated to the issue. The done button doesnt show by default on my side which is what i want since I wish to add a custom done button on top of the select picker so it should be an html element, Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by subtracting the window height with view port height. w

hen select box triggered onfocus, wait for the viewport to change by using a setinterval with 100 milliseconds and then, when it change, wait for another 500 milliseconds (settimeout) after that just to be sure the viewport fully changed. subtract window height with view port and youll get the height of the select box that appeared at the bottom.